# cat: /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases: No such file or directory

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, dnsmasq, raspberrypi

I've searched all over the internet, but couldn't find any answers of my problem..

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi to my laptop. But whenever i try to check the ip address of my raspberry, i get this following notification:

```
cat: /var/lib/misc/dnsmasq.leases: No such file or directory
```

So that means i have no dnsmasq.leases document. Since i am new to ubuntu i have no idea if it is a common thing. Should i create a new dnsmasq.leases in that directory? If yes and how?

Comment: read this https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46154

Comment: i read it, but there are no solution for my problem

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you're trying to accomplish? I'm unsure why you're `cat`ing the dnsmasq.leases file when you're trying to get the IP of your Pi

Comment: How are you trying to check the IP address of the Pi?

Answer (score 0):

To show your IP addresses, try a command like this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:ba:f9:11 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:ba:f9:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.187/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 55664sec preferred_lft 55664sec
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:feba:f912/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

If that doesn't work, let us know what the errors are when you run the command.

Comment: Using `ìfconfig` is another possibility (although deprecated).